# 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#

The full error code:

> Error CS1929  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, TSource)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

```
  string[] terms = new string[31];
```

I'm trying to see if an array contains something in my Excel file. (Using Interop)

```
if (terms.Contains(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1].Value.ToString())) ;
{

}
```

Why is Contains not working here?

I searched and apparently, it has something to do with the type not being the same, but in this case, it is. They are both strings.

Comment: Make sure you are `using System.Linq`.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I already have it.

Comment: *they are both strings.* No they're not. The variable `terms` is not a string. It is a string[]. You can't search an array of strings the same way you search a string. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array (`string[]`) implements `IList` and therefore should have `Contains(object o)` method. But [implementation is explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336401(v=vs.110).aspx), meaning that access to that method is possible only if class is treated as interface:

```
if (((IList)terms).Contains(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1].Value.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an extension method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains`.

`string[]` is an `IEnumerable<string>` so you can use this.

Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file to use it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is why is the compiler binding to `Queryable.Contains` instead of `Enumerable.Contains`?

Comment: This failed for me. I already have **using System.Linq;** at the top of the file, but still get this error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.Exists` and pass a comparison lambda expression:

```
if (Array.Exists(terms, elem => elem == xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1].Value.ToString()))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
using System.Linq;
```

also helps

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
using System.Linq; //Added to top of code
...
...
string[] someList = {"First", "Second", "Third"}; //In your method

bool result = someList.Contains("First")) //equals true;
bool result2 = someList.Contains("Fourth")) //equals false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`string[]` unlike `List<string>` has no `Contains()` method. You'll need to run a loop through your array and compare each index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
{
    if (terms[i].Contains(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1].Value.ToString()))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

However, instead of doing this I suggest you just use `List<string>`. With that you can use `List.Contains()` the same way you're trying to do in your example. In C# lists are superior to arrays in most cases.

Comment: it actually has `Contains(object o)` method, because it implement IList

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue when mixing up **StringComparison** with **StringComparer**. StringComparer is the on you need when using .Where on a string array in linq.

```
installationOverviews = installationOverviews.Where(x => request.InstallationNumbers.Contains(x.InstallationNumber, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

Or

```
installationOverviews = installationOverviews.Where(x => request.InstallationNumbers.Select(e => e.ToUpper()).Contains(x.InstallationNumber.ToUpper())).ToArray();
```